# Undefined symbols, while building C project with homebrew library

Tags: c, macos, build, homebrew, clion

I try to run a simple project to check if the library (libnfc) are correctly loaded, and apparently the project find the lib and all the code in it but while building it does find more lib.

- PC version: Mac, Apple M1, Ventura 13.3.1
- Homebrew: 4.1.11
- CLion: 232.9921.42 (latest)

This is the error while compiling (I'm using CLion):

```
FAILED: NFC_Reader 
: && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -I/opt/homebrew/include  -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/opt/homebrew/lib CMakeFiles/NFC_Reader.dir/NFC_UID_reader.c.o -o NFC_Reader   && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_nfc_version", referenced from:
      _main in NFC_UID_reader.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(NFC_Reader C)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-L/opt/homebrew/lib " CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "-I/opt/homebrew/include " CACHE STRING "" FORCE )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I/opt/homebrew/include " CACHE STRING "" FORCE)


add_executable(NFC_Reader NFC_UID_reader.c)
```

And this is my main class:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <nfc/nfc.h>
#include <printf.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s", nfc_version());
}
```

All the lib are installed correctly, do anyone have some ideas?

Im trying to use homebrew library into CLion via MakeLists.txt

Comment: Your final build command does _not_ have `-lnfc` in it. So, even with `-L` to point to the correct directory, the linker will _not_ try to search for (e.g. `libnfc.so` et. al.). So, you need to change your `Makelists.txt` to tell `cmake` that when you are building the target that it should include the NFC library. See: [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/5382650)

Comment: you mean that i must add a CMake target_link_libraries?